# Symmetric square matrix of positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

A symmetric square matrix of positive definite $n$ order is defined as

> if $\forall x\in { \mathbb{R} }^{ n }$, $x\neq 0$, $x^T Ax>0$, equivalently it is $\left< x,Ax \right> >0$.

I can not find the way to prove this equivalence, nor can I find a general way to prove equality $\left< Px,Px \right> =\left< x, P^t Px \right> $, $P$ matrix order $n$.

Of course, for particular cases like $n = 2$, the demonstration of the second question is simple.

Comment: $x^TAx$ and $\langle x, Ax\rangle $ are exactly the same thing, since the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ of $x$ and $y$ is simply defined as $x^Ty$.

Comment: The definition of the [adjoint operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) ($P^T$) is given through the inner product -- $<x,Ay>  = <A^T x,y>$ defines what $A^T$ means.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof of equivalence:** Note that for any vectors $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$, we have $\langle x,y \rangle = x^Ty$. It follows that
$$
\langle x,Ax \rangle = x^T(Ax) = x^TAx
$$
**Proof of equality:** Note that
$$
\langle Px,Px \rangle = (Px)^T(Px) = (x^TP^T)(Px) = x^T(P^TPx) = \langle x,P^TPx \rangle
$$